# Calling a method only once in an updateScore function in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, ios, sprite-kit

This works fine, but obviously it's messy and I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do this. Having to constantly remember to flip the bool back is a pain, is there anything else I can do here?  I take it `SpriteKit` itself doesn't have any convenience method for calling something only once for example.

```
func updateScore() {

        // MARK: Increase Difficulty
        switch score {
        case 0:
            if !levelToggle {
                showLevelGraphic(1)
                levelToggle = true
            }
        case 1:
            levelToggle = false
        case 5:
            if !lighteningToggle {
                GameEffects.lightening(self, masterNode: worldNode, backgroundStringName: "background")
                GameEffects.lightening(self, masterNode: worldNode, backgroundStringName: "foreground")
                GameEffects.shakeScreen(worldNode)
                lighteningToggle = true
            }

            if !rainToggle {
                makeItRain()
                rainToggle = true
            }
            break
        case 6:
            lighteningToggle = false
        case 10:
            if !rotateToggle {
                GameEffects.rotateScreenAndHold(worldNode, finishAngle: 0.06, totalEffectDuration: 5.0)
                rotateToggle = true
            }
        case 15:
            rotateToggle = false
        case 16:
            if !rotateToggle {
                GameEffects.rotateScreenAndHold(worldNode, finishAngle: -0.06, totalEffectDuration: 5.0)
                rotateToggle = true
            }
             break
        case 17:
            rotateToggle = false
        case 20:
            stopRaining()
            rainToggle = false
        case 25:
            if !rotateToggle {
                GameEffects.rotateScreenAndHold(worldNode, finishAngle: -0.06, totalEffectDuration: 10.0)
                rotateToggle = true
            }
        case 26:
            rotateToggle = false
        case 45:
            break
        case 50:
            if !levelToggle {
                showLevelGraphic(2)
                levelToggle = true
            }
            kGroundSpeed = 200
            break
        case 55:
            if !zoomToggle {
                GameEffects.zoomIn(worldNode)
            }
        case 56:
            zoomToggle = false
        case 70:
            if !rotateToggle {
                GameEffects.rotateScreenAndHold(worldNode, finishAngle: 0.06, totalEffectDuration: 10.0)
                rotateToggle = true
            }
```

Comment: Can we assume that the score can never decrease in this game?

Comment: Yes that is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  use properties,  they are your best friend

```
var rotateToggle = false
{
    didSet
    {
        if(rotateToggle)
        {
            GameEffects.rotateScreenAndHold(worldNode, finishAngle: -0.06, totalEffectDuration: 5.0)
        }
        else
        {
            //if you need something on false, do it here
        }
    }
}
```

do this for all of your other toggles.

Update for score property:

```
var score : UInt = 0
{
    didSet
    {
        updateScore()
    }
}
```

Now we have your case statement, chain them together

```
switch (score)
{
    case 0:
      levelToggle = true
    case 1:
      levelToggle = false
    case 10,16,25:
      rotateToggle = true
//...etc
}
```

of course, how you have toggle set up, this requires score increases by 1, and updateScore gets fired afterwards before score can increase by 1 again.

Comment: Thanks so much, I still can't get my head around your code though..updateScore is called inside `override func updateWithDeltaTime(seconds: NSTimeInterval) ` in my app, so it's getting called constantly (not just when the score increases), so is your approach flipping the bool back to false after the effect is run, so that it won't run repeatedly as per my original code?

Comment: if you do the updateScore logic inside a property, then the only time the function gets fired is when score changes,  which is what you should be doing.  Avoid doing things in the update loop unless you need it to update every frame,  you only have 16ms to play with

Comment: "the only time the function gets fired is when score changes" but does it only fire once?

Comment: it fires one time when score changes firing every update seems silly

Comment: right but that's what it was doing prior to my adding the bool/flag (because updateScore is being called inside updateWIthDeltaTime)

Comment: I  do not know what we are talking about here or what the malfunction is, if you want it to not update every cycle, do not put it in the update function

Comment: well, its in there because I needed to update the score very often..but using your approach, could I write score as a computed property and put my switch statement inside it instead?

Comment: already provided the code to do it, you do it as a property so that when score changes, the method gets called.  So if for some reason update is paused, and you change score, it will still do the function